# Fax number data ignored in vCard (vcf file)

Tags: php, vcf-vcard

I am writing a Vcard (vcf file) generator for my client and she wants to include the fax number of the users in the db.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard');  
$name="richard.lee";
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename= "'.$name.'.vcf"'); 

$delimitor="\r\n";

echo "BEGIN:VCARD". $delimitor;
echo "N:Lee;Richard;;;". $delimitor;
echo "ADR;TYPE=intl,work,postal,parcel:;;Rm 1234, 1/F., Test Address, Kowloon Tong;Hong Kong". $delimitor;
echo "EMAIL;INTERNET:richard.lee@testtest.org.hk". $delimitor;
echo "ORG:Hong Kong Test Authority". $delimitor;
echo "TEL;WORK:89948800". $delimitor;
echo "TEL;FAX:89948890". $delimitor;
echo "TEL;CELL:52232510". $delimitor;
echo "TITLE:Director - Industry Standards and Practices". $delimitor;
echo "URL;WORK:http://www.testtest.org.hk ". $delimitor;
echo "END:VCARD". $delimitor;
```

When a user visits the link (the PHP script), the browser will download the vCard file and opens it in client (e.g. Outlook), however, all the data are imported into a contact EXCEPT the fax number.

So, what is the reason that the fax number is NOT included in the Vcard import ? Please kindly advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated VCARD works for me, shows the FAX number, and is also validated from online tools. However, it seems like Outlook requires a different syntax: WORK,FAX as Type.

Try this:

1. Declare VCARD version (using v.3 in my example)

```
echo "VERSION:3.0".$delimitor;
```

2. Switch TEL syntax to newer type

```
echo "TEL;type=WORK:89948800".$delimitor;
echo "TEL;type=WORK,FAX:89948890".$delimitor;
echo "TEL;type=CELL:52232510".$delimitor;
```

Complete snippet:

```
echo "BEGIN:VCARD".$delimitor;
echo "VERSION:3.0".$delimitor;
echo "N:Lee;Richard;;;".$delimitor;
echo "ADR;TYPE=intl,work,postal,parcel:;;Rm 1234, 1/F., Test Address, Kowloon Tong;Hong Kong".$delimitor;
echo "EMAIL;INTERNET:richard.lee@testtest.org.hk".$delimitor;
echo "ORG:Hong Kong Test Authority".$delimitor;
echo "TEL;type=WORK:89948800".$delimitor;
echo "TEL;type=WORK,FAX:89948890".$delimitor;
echo "TEL;type=CELL:52232510".$delimitor;
echo "TITLE:Director - Industry Standards and Practices".$delimitor;
echo "URL;WORK:http://www.testtest.org.hk ".$delimitor;
echo "END:VCARD".$delimitor;
```

The fax doesn't show in the preview while you import, but if you open the contact on Outlook, you can see the FAX too:

[image]

Updated after testing on Outlook

Comment: Thanks a lot (I used the new format `echo "TEL;type=WORK,FAX:89948890".$delimitor;` and it works. (but no need to declare version, strange....). Thanks again